# Pandas Dataframe - compute mean on column k based on value on column j being the same, then remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like this

```
columns = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]
values = np.array([[1, 1, 7], [1,1, 8], [1, 2, 5], 
                  [1, 2, 5.5]])
index = ["foo", "foo", "baz","baz"]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index, columns = columns)
df
```

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3
foo 1.0    1.0      7.0
foo 1.0    1.0      8.0
baz 1.0    2.0      5.0
baz 1.0    2.0      5.5
```

The dataframe is such that, taken any two rows, the values in the first two columns `Col1` and `Col2` are the same as long as the index is the same.

What I would like to do is, for each unique index:

- compute the mean for `Col3` for all the rows with said index
- remove all the rows with said index, but one
- replace the `Col3` value with what calculated in the first step

For the given example, the desired output is hence

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3
foo 1.0      1.0    7.50
baz 1.0      2.0    5.25
```

I am totally unable to find an elegant approach.
I tried to make use of `dataframe.groupby`. I would need to add a fresh index, something like

```
df.reset_index().groupby("index", sort=False)["Col3"].mean()
```

outputting

```
 index
 foo    7.50
 baz    5.25
 Name: Col3, dtype: float64
```

but I still have to add these values "manually", as well as deleting duplicates.

I am wondering if there is a pandas-like gracious way to achieve the aim in one sweep, thanks.

Comment: Try: `df.groupby(level=0, sort=False).mean()`.

Comment: goodness me, a one liner, was hoping for something similar, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agg` as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
columns = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]
values = np.array([[1, 1, 7], [1,1, 8], [1, 2, 5], 
                  [1, 2, 5.5]])
index = ["foo", "foo", "baz","baz"]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index, columns = columns)
df = df.reset_index().groupby(['index']).agg({'Col3': 'mean',
                                              'Col1': 'min',
                                              'Col2': 'min'})
df.head()
```